# How to view disassembly for optimized speed builds in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, assembly, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I have a C program in Visual Studio where I would like to compare the disassembly between the standard debug build and a build where speed is optimized.

For standard debug things work perfectly, I set a breakpoint and then right-click "Goto Dissassembly" to view the equivalent assembly code.

However, when I try to do that when the optimized for speed switch is enabled, I only see part of the assembly.

My procedure for creating an optimized speed build is (staying in the debug build configuration):

1. From the project properties -> C/C++->Optimization change Optimization from disabled /Od to Optimize for maximize speed /O2 and changing favor Size or Speed to 'Favor Fast Code /Ot)
2. Under Code Generation ->Basic Runtime checks change to 'Default'

Note: I decided to modify my debug configuration and not do a full optimization (which includes size) because I wanted to preserve my code symbols.

As part of my investigation, I created a trivial program for testing. Here is the source:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    printf("The value of x is %d\n", x);
    while (1)
    {
        ++x;
        if (x > 1000000)
           break;
    }
    y = x;
    printf("The value of y is %d\n", y);
    return 0;
}
```

In full debug mode here is my disassembly: Note: I can easily see what is happening in the WHILE LOOP

```
int x = 0;
00CF1779  mov         dword ptr [x],0  
int y = 0;
00CF1780  mov         dword ptr [y],0  
printf("The value of x is %d\n", x);
00CF1787  mov         eax,dword ptr [x]  
00CF178A  push        eax  
00CF178B  push        offset string "The value of x is %d\n" (0CF6B30h)  
00CF1790  call        _printf (0CF1320h)  
00CF1795  add         esp,8  
while (1)
00CF1798  mov         eax,1  
00CF179D  test        eax,eax  
00CF179F  je          main+47h (0CF17B7h)  
{
    ++x;
00CF17A1  mov         eax,dword ptr [x]  
00CF17A4  add         eax,1  
00CF17A7  mov         dword ptr [x],eax  
    if (x > 1000000)
00CF17AA  cmp         dword ptr [x],0F4240h  
00CF17B1  jle         main+45h (0CF17B5h)  
        break;
00CF17B3  jmp         main+47h (0CF17B7h)  
}
00CF17B5  jmp         main+28h (0CF1798h)  
y = x;
00CF17B7  mov         eax,dword ptr [x]  
00CF17BA  mov         dword ptr [y],eax  
printf("The value of y is %d\n", y);
00CF17BD  mov         eax,dword ptr [y]  
00CF17C0  push        eax  
00CF17C1  push        offset string "The value of y is %d\n" (0CF6BE8h)  
00CF17C6  call        _printf (0CF1320h)  
00CF17CB  add         esp,8  

return 0;
```

Here is the disassembly from the optimized speed build - note there is no code shown for the while loop routine

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
printf("The value of x is %d\n", x);
00EE16F0  push        0  
00EE16F2  push        offset string "The value of x is %d\n" (0EE6B30h)  
00EE16F7  call        _printf (0EE1320h)  
while (1)
{
    ++x;
    if (x > 1000000)
        break;
}
y = x;
printf("The value of y is %d\n", y);
00EE16FC  push        0F4241h  
00EE1701  push        offset string "The value of y is %d\n" (0EE6BE8h)   
00EE1706  call        _printf (0EE1320h)  
00EE170B  add         esp,10h  

return 0;
00EE170E  xor         eax,eax  
}
00EE1710  ret
```

Both builds output the same values for x and y in the printf statements.
Does anyone know how to solve my problem?

Comment: It is entirely normal, removing unnecessary code is the job of the optimizer.  It can easily tell, so can you, that the while loop is pointless and that the final value for x will always be 1000001.  So that's what the push  0F4241h instruction does.  The optimizer in the machine is not quite a substitute for the optimizer between a programmer's ears, but it tries to get close.

Comment: @HansPassant - So you are saying that the optimzer skips the while loop and does the eqivalent of x=1000001?

Comment: @HansPassant - I believe you are correct.  I just made my while loop more complicated and now I see the familiar infinite code in the assembly as well.

Comment: *"Both builds output the same values for x and y in the printf statements."*: exactly, that's all what you can "see" outside, so that's all what optimizer left. Things like manipulating with files, calling device-drivers, system services, etc. can't be removed, because the app would behave differently. Anything internal like calculations can be changed by optimizer. There are sometimes some grey areas, like f.e. changing divisions by constants into multiplications, where the result may be fractionally different, but these optimizations often require additional optimizer flags to be enabled.